# Is it possible to highlight the non-breakable space in zsh / terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh, console

I’m looking for possibility to somehow highlight the non-breakable space (`\xA0`) in the shell output to distinguish it from the normal space during debug sessions. E. g., I would like to see the output of `$ echo -e "[\xC2\xA0]|[ ]"` like:

```
[_]|[ ]
```

Colors, underscores, even blinking is OK. I even can switch from `zsh` to any shell where it’s configurable enough. Is it at least possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This highlighting is IMHO more easily implemented in the terminal emulator than in the shell. And as a benefit you get the highlighting independent from the shell -- so it's even working with `less` etc.
Since you are fine with switching the shell, I suppose you are fine with switching to [URxVt](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode), too.

In conjunction with the perl extentions [urxvt-perls](https://github.com/muennich/urxvt-perls) it is possible to make URLs etc. clickable. But we can abuse this feature just to underline the non-breakable spaces.

The configuration is done in `~/.Xdefaults`:

```
URxvt.perl-ext:           default,matcher
URxvt.matcher.button:     2
URxvt.matcher.pattern.0:  (\\240)
URxvt.matcher.launcher.0: /bin/true
```

- line 1 activates the appropriate extension
- line 2 configures the usage of the middle mouse button for clicking on the ,,hyperlink''
- line 3 defines the regex to match, here every non-breakable space; `A0 (hex) = 240 (oct)`
- line 4 defines the action, in your case you don't want to open up a browser or any program, so `/bin/true` should be fine

Reload `~/.Xdefaults` by restarting the X server (this might be overkill, but I'm not sure if a `xrdb ~/.Xdefaults` is sufficient...) and you get your desired result. With a magnifying glass it is even possible to distinguish between non-breakable spaces an underscores (notice the shift by 1 pixel) `;)`:

[image]

---

The following is kind of a *proof of concept* for a "backend" solution. Be aware, that this will break a lot of things, namely interactive programs like `man`, `less` etc. (`vim` is complaining but still working). This approach was posted by Atom Smasher on the `zsh-users` mailinglist on [Sat, 16 May 2009](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users//2009/msg00498.html) to colorize `STDERR`. I adopted it to your requirements:

```
# ## highlight_nbs.zsh ##

zmodload zsh/terminfo zsh/system
autoload colors is-at-least

if [[ "${terminfo[colors]}" -ge 8 ]] { colors }

highlight_nbs() {
  while sysread line
  do
    syswrite "${line//$'\xC2\xA0'/${bg[red]} ${terminfo[sgr0]}}"
  done
}

precmd() { sleep 0 }

## i'm not sure exactly how far back it's safe to go with this
## 4.3.4 works; 4.2.1 hangs.
is-at-least 4.3.4 && exec  > >(highlight_nbs)
```

The tricky part is `exec  > >(highlight_nbs)` which processes the complete output of the replacing shell through the `highlight_nbs` function. The `precmd` definition is necessary to avoid a race condition, otherwise the new prompt is printed before the actual output of the executed command.

Here is a demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be a quirk-mode solution. While it likely might solve the problem temporary on per-debug-session basis, it still hardly helps with remote (say, `ssh`) sessions. That’s kinda _frontend_ solution and I still hope to find a _backend_ one. But thank you anyway, this at least solves me the problem for the moment.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Perhaps you can elaborate on your requirements in your question. From my point of view a _frontend solution_ (how you call it) is even superior as it's independent of the system you are logged into (via ssh or what-so-ever). As long as you work with "your" computer and urxvt you get the highlighting. Or is it the other way round: You log into _one_ remote system from _different_ machines?!

Comment: yes, in general the problem to be solved is following: I have an amount of computers as ssh-clients, and a bundle of ssh-hosts. I would like to have kinda “yadr-like” setup on remotes.

Comment: @mudasobwa : I added an idea for a "backend" solution. It is far from being perfect, but perhaps it's of some use for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

```
$ echo -e "[\xC2\xA0]|[ ]" | cat -A
[M-BM- ]|[ ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac you might consider using iTerm with [this hack](https://gitlab.com/therwe/marknonbreakingspace). It is also shell-agnostic.

It changes the background color of an NBSP, using the 'Trigger' feature in iTerm.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: I clearly stated in tags I am using the robust operating system, not MacOS.